# Weird NSLog behaviour: NSLog displaying window controller's window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nslog, nswindowcontroller

I dont understand what's happening here. I have a button wired up to the below action in AppDelegate:

```
- (IBAction)openWindow:(id)sender {
    self.winCon = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"NewWindow"];
}
```

On click of the button nothing happens (as expected), but when I change the code to(add `NSLog()`)

```
- (IBAction)openWindow:(id)sender {
    self.winCon = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"NewWindow"];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.winCon.window);
}
```

A the window of 'NewWindow' pops up. Why does this happen?
Also the NSLog prints `(null)` in the console.

(In the 'NewWindow' xib the file's owner is NSObject and I haven't wired up the window reference. So I was expecting the log to print `null` , but the window being displayed was a surprise)

Another thing, when I use:

```
- (IBAction)openWindow:(id)sender {
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"NewWindow" owner:self.winCon];
}
```

on click of the button, the window gets displayed. Why does this happen? **Isn't loading nib and displaying window separated processes. Shouldn't I be calling the `showWindow:` or `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` to display the window?**

When I read a particular piece of apple docs in [window programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/OpeningClosingWindows.html):

> Opening a window—that is, making a window visible—is normally
>   accomplished by placing the window into the application's window list
>   by invoking one of the methods makeKeyAndOrderFront:, orderFront:,
>   etc., in NSWindow, and so on. **Also, with certain bits set in
>   Interface Builder, the window is shown when the nib file is loaded in
>   some cases.**

I guess this is the reason for `loadNibNamed:..` to open the window. But what are these 'bits set in Interface Builder'. Where can I get information on this? (Also I could prevent the window from opening in the above case when I uncheck **'visible at launch'** property of the window - It would help if some more explanation of what this property does.) Thanks.

Note: I am aware of how to initialize the nib using a NSWindowController subclass and do the proper wiring up in the xib, but I'm just curious about the above behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, when you write `NSLog(@"%@",self.winCon.window);` you are actually sending a message to the window controller instance `winCon` to display its window, and then sending it an additional `description` message to output a string that will be displayed in the console. Written in the normal message passing syntax (not dot notation) and using a "%s" in the format string, you are doing this: `NSLog(@"%s",[[[self winCon] window] description]`. As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the window method will return the window instance *and* attempt to load the window if it has not been displayed already.

The `loadNibNamed:owner:` NSBundle method should only be used when you aren't using a window controller. Loading a nib file and displaying the window are two separate actions. If you haven't done so already, you should read up on the File Owner placeholder and how xib files are archived into nib files. That being said, your showWindow method should look like the following (although you really should subclass the NSWindowController and already have it initialized - let me know if that doesn't make sense):

```
- (IBAction)openWindow:(id)sender {
    self.winCon = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"NewWindow"];
    [self.winCon showWindow];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on window method, but loading the window and displaying the windows is different right? Also why does the log state ment return null. And regarding loadNibNamed:owner: the fact that loading nib and displaying window are separate actions is the cause of my doubt. Why should a call to `loadNibNamed:owner:` display the window. I'll add more details to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: In the docs its all loading the window, but says nothing about displaying the window.